# Learning Python The Hard Way Example 15 Python shell problems

Tags: python, shell

As the title says, I'm having issues with running commands through python shell, more specifically, I can't seem to figure out how to open and read files like it tells me to do in the study drill.

here's everything I've done so far:

```
PS C:\Users\NikoSuave\Desktop\learn python the hard way\works in progress or finished> python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:03:49) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from sys import argv
>>> script, filename = argv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
>>> txt = open(filename)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'filename' is not defined
>>> filename = argv
>>> script = argv
>>> txt = open(filename)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found
```

what am I doing wrong? and If i'm way off, could one of you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: `filename=argv` is wrong. argv is a list.`filename` needs to be a string.That's why `open(filename)` raises an error.

Comment: In interactive mode no arguments are passed to the script hence `argv` is `['']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sys.argv` is a list in Python, which contains the command-line arguments passed to the script. So this is generally used when you run a python prog. using command line like:

```
python prog.py arg1 arg2
```

Here `arg1` and `arg2` are present in the `argv` list. While being in REPL no arguments are passed to hence `argv` is empty. This is the reason you keep getting `ValueError`, `NameError`...

As for opening a file, it like: `file_object = open(filename, mode)` where `mode` can be `r, w, a, r+` (read, write, append and both read-write). An example would be:

```
file = open("newfile.txt", "w")
file.write("hello world in the new file\n")
file.write("and another line\n")
file.close()
```

The code above opens `newfile.txt` for write and adds the content shown. Finally closes the file. Similar thing is available while reading the file:

```
file = open("newfile.txt", "r")
print file.read()
```

This reads the file `newfile.txt` and prints the content.

Comment: This will you a `file` object on which when you call the `read()` method you get the file content. you might want to go thru https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: Thank you so much this makes alot of sense. My only other question, is if you have any advice for people like me, new to programming?

Comment: The python doc are really easy to understand of lots of examples. I would suggest go for some simple coding questions and try them yourself, look at the documentation/stackoverflow when you have any questions (you can try:https://github.com/gregmalcolm/python_koans)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we open files with strings or defined strings.

```
>>> txt = open(filename)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'filename' is not defined

This is not how we open files with python, you need strings.
txt=open("filename.txt") #if is it a txt file
```

or

```
filename="filename.txt" #if its a .txt file
txt=open(filename)
```

In this problem:

```
>>> filename = argv
>>> script = argv
>>> txt = open(filename)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found
```

sys.argv returning lists, python whining about need string or buffer, not list. So you have to reach every element in the list and put them to correct place.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are supposed to create a .py file. Then run the file with an argument, the name of another text file. sys.argv gets the arguments from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to call the file in console. For Example, Save the following code in example.py

```
from sys import argv

print "Argument 1 is " , argv[1]
print "Argument 2 is " , argv[2]
print "Argument 3 is " , argv[3]
```

and use

```
python example.py one two three
```

will print

```
Argument 1 is  one
Argument 2 is  two
Argument 3 is  three
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a module file1.py

```
from sys import argv

print 'argv:-', argv

file_name = argv[1]
print 'file_name:-', file_name

with open(file_name, 'w') as fp:
    # your file operations
```

And you want to get file_name from user via command prompt.

```
$ python file1.py myfile.txt
argv:- ['file1.py', 'myfile.txt']
file_name:- myfile.txt
```

So `argv[0]` holds the module name itself and `argv[1]` is holding the filename or path user passed ie. `myfile.txt`.